# How to get repos from a specific team using GitHub API?

Tags: github

I have a script to download all the repos in my Organization, and it works fine.

We have recently added Teams, and I would like to target a specific team to download all the repos in that team.

To get for the whole org I can do this: (changing the page number to walk them)

**Works:**

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/repos?access_token=MY_TOKEN&per_page=100&page=1
```

How do I do it for a team in the Org? I've tried:

**Does not work**

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/teams/TEAM_SLUG/repos?access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

As well as a few others, none of which works.

By looking at the [API Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/teams/#list-teams) it seems like what I'm trying should work. I can't even get the list of teams which the docs have as:

```
GET /orgs/:org/teams/:team_slug
```

So if I do:

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/teams/TEAM_SLUG?access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

I just get back a Not Found, error with a link to the docs.

Anyone have success in doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not trying correct API to get the Repos in a team

try

```
GET /teams/:team_id/repos
```

To get the team ID you can list all your Organisation teams as follows:

```
GET https://api.github.com/orgs/<ORGANISATION>/teams
```

If you are self hosting your GitHub Enterprise then replace `https://api.github.com` with `https://<HOSTNAME>/api/v3/`

Send personal access token as:

```
Authorization: token <PERSONALACCESSTOKEN>
```

**Using Curl:**

To get team Repos:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token <PERSONALACCESSTOKEN>" -X GET https://api.github.com/teams/:team_id/repos
```

To get the team ID :

```
curl -H "Authorization: token PERSONALACCESSTOKEN" -X GET https://api.github.com/orgs/<ORGANISATION>/teams
```

Further reading:

API Authentication: https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Listing teams: https://developer.github.com/v3/teams/#list-team-repos

Comment: was this useful?

Comment: Github Apis can be used to get the other details of team as well

Comment: Yes it was useful thanks! Getting an empty JSON array, but that is because the repos are not assigned to the team correctly, so just a setup issue.